# Why program freezes when I add instance of Form in user control in C#?

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and using windows forms. 
I have `Form1` with a button (Button_Save) and `textbox` . and I have user control1 with one button (`button1`).

What I am trying to do in this program is: when I click on `button1`, its text appear in `textbox` (in `Form1`), then I enter new text and click save, the `button1` text change accordingly.

I will explain when the freeze happens:

There are 2 parts:

first part:  when I created instance of user control1 in `Form1` then I participated in `UserControl1Event` and run program it works fine and `button1` text appears in `textbox` when I click on it. Second part when I create instance of `Form1` in user control1 and participated in Form1Event and run the program the program freezes for long time then gives error pointing at `Form1` instance in user control1 (as shown in screen shot).

Anyone knows why this is happening ? what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler Form1Event;

    UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Controls.Add(uc1);
        uc1.Visible = true;
        uc1.UserControl1Event += new EventHandler(Handleuc1);
    }


    string Return_TextBox_Txt;
    public string TextBox_Txt
    {
        get { return Return_TextBox_Txt; }

    }



    public void Handleuc1(object sender, EventArgs e) ////////////Handle uc1  event 
    {
        textBox1.Text = uc1.ButtonText;

    }



   private void button_save__Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//change button text
    {
        Return_TextBox_Txt = textBox1.Text;

        Form1Event(this, e);
    }

 }
```

User Control1:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{


    string BtnTxt;



    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();

    public event EventHandler UserControl1Event;



    public string ButtonText 
    {
        get { return BtnTxt; }

    }


    private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        frm1.Form1Event += new EventHandler(HandleForm1Event);


    }

    public void HandleForm1Event(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

        button1.Text = frm1.TextBox_Txt;
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BtnTxt = button1.Text;

        UserControl1Event(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you created an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's expected behavior because of you are creating new `Form1` instance and on object constructing it creates new `UserControl1` instance that also creates new `Form1` instance and so on.

If you need to have an owner of `UserControl1` inside its instance you can pass it to the `UserControl1` constructor:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ...
    UserControl1 uc1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // creates new control and pass owner via constructor parameter
        uc1 = new UserControl1(this);
        Controls.Add(uc1);
        uc1.Visible = true;
        uc1.UserControl1Event += new EventHandler(Handleuc1);
    }
    ...
}

public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    Form1 frm1;
    public UserControl1(Form1 owner)
    {
        // save user control owner passed from constructor parameter to local variable
        frm1 = owner;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that both of your classes depend on each other.

`Form1`, when created, creates an instance of `UserControl1`, which in turn creates and instance of `Form1`, and so on. All this chained creation eventually makes your code throw a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: @Kate: Vadim Martynov's answer is the way to go usually.